# Why div and marque in separate line?

Tags: html, css

it is as [what i don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOgRF.png),
i want it as [what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTUn9.png),
My code is

```
<div id='news'>Breaking news:</div><marquee>This is a test</marquee>
```

Comment: Enclose your marquee tag inside the div tag

Comment: because both are block elements :P set width for both and float:left

Comment: here is a fiddle to it http://jsfiddle.net/TmJCE/849/

Comment: Check out this https://jsfiddle.net/q9uusz92/

Comment: Besides the comments given: [Don't use it](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee)

Comment: ...and `<marquee>` has been deprecated and should not be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `float: left;` in your div and marquee css. That will do the trick.